# Watch changes in a file and restart python script

Tags: python, linux, shell, watch, inotify

I want to restart a python script(restart.py) whenever some edits a file (test.txt)

=====restart.py====

```
from time import sleep
for i in range (1000):
    print (i)
    sleep(2)
```

Then Im watching for changes using this command

```
 inotify-hookable -f test.txt  -c "sh kill.sh"
```

====kill.sh=====

```
#!/bin/sh
ps -ef | grep restart | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 restart.py
```

Now whats happening is that the very first time I edit test.txt, it kills the restart.py script and starts it again. But after that if i make any changes , it doesnt kill and start the script again. So in a way inotify works for only first edit of the test.txt file and never again. How can I make it execute "kill & restart" whenever there is an edit in test.txt file ?

```
─╯
Fri Apr 29 01:58:15 2022 : Starting up, watching files <test>
Fri Apr 29 01:58:15 2022 : FINISHED setting up watches. Took 0.00s with 1 watches added, 0 removed, 0 replaced. Have 1 total watches
Fri Apr 29 01:58:35 2022 : Had changes in your paths
Fri Apr 29 01:58:35 2022 : Running global hooks
Fri Apr 29 01:58:35 2022 : Running <sh kill.sh>
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

----------------------TRIAL 2-----------------

Here i tried this python script with watchdog, but even this is not working. Works for the first time I edit the test.txt file, thereafter it doesnt restart/kill the hello.py script at all

```
import time
from threading import Timer
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import os,signal
from time import sleep
import icecream as ic

def kill_process(name):
    #pid_=999999999
    for line in os.popen("ps ax | grep " + name + " | grep -v grep"):
        fields = line.split()
        print (fields[0])
        pid = fields[0]
        print ("PID==",pid)

    ic(pid)
    return pid

class  MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def  on_modified(self,  event):
         if len(event.src_path)>0:
             print(f'event type: {event.event_type} path : {event.src_path}')

             try:
                 pd=kill_process("hello.py")
                 os.kill(int(pd), signal.SIGKILL)
             except:
                 os.system("python3.7 hello.py 1")


if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    event_handler = MyHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler,  path='test.txt',  recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while  True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except  KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

╰─❯ cat hello.py                                                                                                                                    ─╯

```
from time import sleep
for i in range (1000):
    print (i)
    sleep(10)
```

Comment: Can it possible the file was deleted and recreated ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use one of the python modules that wraps `inotify` and deal with this from within the script?

Comment: @Ôrel No the file is just being edited, never deleted

Comment: What do you get with `inotifywait -m test.txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to launch a finishing command

You can solve your issue by adding a `&` on restart launch

```
#!/bin/sh
ps -ef | grep restart | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 restart.py&
```